# IE9 weird javascript issue

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

In IE9 Beta, i am not able to access javascript variables in a child window from the parent window.

```
var mywin = window.open('popup.jsp', 'popup', 'width=400,height=200,scrollbars=yes');

if(mywin.foo == 'bar') {
   // do something
}
```

popup.jsp contains a script like this

> `var foo = 'bar';`

The condition inside the if block is truthy in every other browser except IE9. In IE9 *mywin.foo* is *undefined*.

Can someone shed some light on this?

Comment: popupjsp is on the same domain as the surrounding page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was fixed in IE9 RC1. Seems to be an IE bug.